# Как запретить изменять информацию на сайте соц кнопкам?

Tags: php, mysql

Я уже задавал подобный вопрос, дело в том, что он ловит id и меняет его, как мне сделать так, чтоб он не мог его менять, код соц кнопок может быть любой.

Comment: мне сказали нужно воспользоваться вот этим но я не знаю как $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']

Comment: Наверное, они хотели сказать, что надо запретить вход с рефером - соц сетью. Но это не совсем верно, т.к. тогда и обычные пользователи по ссылкам с соц сетей не смогут входить, да и скорее всего данные неправильные будут передаваться соц сети и кнопки будут не работать.
Если все же слишком надо, то поддерживаю Asen.

Или еще можно, как вариант, вместо кнопок использовать картинки. Т.е. пользователь кликает на картинку и его редиректит на добавление записи. Просто в ссылку надо подставить текущий url.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй каждый раз генерировать случайное id, допустим 6-8 символов, используя средства PHP.

Comment: как пример пожалуйста я не могу генерировать каждый раз id у меня по нему статьи привязаны

Comment: Можете показать свой сайт, чтобы я примерно понял его структуру?

Comment: нет не могу можем только в скайпе поговорить

Comment: А кстати, в каком смысле "меняет id" в смысле лезет в исходник и переписывает его по-своему или как? Странно, что за лажная социальная кнопка такая? Ведь изменить id - это нарушить работу целой страницы, если не всего сайта!

Comment: да получается что так давайте это обсудим мой скайп palosh65 хочется понять корень проблемы поможете?может быть надо изменить ссылки кнопок т е давать им не оригинальную название ссылки а перекодированное как вы думаете но как сделать я не знаю